# C++ wrapper for the Observer pattern

Tags: c++, function, parameters

C++ newbie. I have a class with a vector of listeners following the observer pattern. Listeners inherit from an abstract class defining different methods like on_start, on_stop, on_such_event, etc. *These methods are not having the same signature.*

I'd like to write an event processing method and call from it, when appropriate, the registered listeners, with the appropriate methods and providing the needed arguments. I could, of course, call in a loop the appropriate method for each listener. But this is not DRY and code is difficult to follow.

Is it possible to have a function wrapping my above calls? Something like

```
void notify_listeners(?);
```

where "?" stands for something I don't know right now. notify_listeners() would call each registered listener with the appropriate method and arguments. I'd like to call this from my evens processing method like this:

```
if (some_event)
  notify_listeners(on_start(some arguments)); // calls on_start for each listener
if (other_event)
  notify_listeners(on_stop(some other arguments));
```

"on_start" and "on_stop" are in a header as public method defined by the listeners. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function in this manner:

```
template <typename ...Params, typename ...Args>
void notify_listeners(void (MyBase::*method)(Params...), const Args &... args)
{
    for (MyBase *listener : all_listeners)
        (listener->*method)(args...);
}
```

Where `MyBase` is a class that all listeners inherit from, that has the `on_...` methods.

Then call it like this:

```
foo.notify_liteners(&MyBase::on_start, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks! Syntax is not obvious with templates and I have a lot to learn. But the usage simplicity is beautiful!What is "foo" in your example?

Comment: @YetAnotherNick An object of a class that contains the list of listeners, and that has `notify_listeners` as a method. Or do you have the list of listeners in a global variable, with `notify_listeners` as a free function? Then you don't need `foo.` of course.

Comment: Thanks! Syntax is not obvious with templates and I have a lot to learn. But the usage simplicity is beautiful! What is `code`foo`code` in your example? Also, for this call `code`notify_listeners(&listener::Listener::on_game_finished())`code` I'm getting `code`cannot call member function ‘virtual void listener::Listener::on_game_finished()’ without object`code`...

Comment: @YetAnotherNick Remove the `()`.

Comment: Simply amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @YetAnotherNick You're welcome! You can press the green tick next to the answer to mark your question as solved.